# Kivy App running video; Tap event not working

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm working on kivy framework (v1.10). I'm trying to create a simple module that runs a video in loop and exits the application once someone taps on the screen. NOTE: I'm developing this application for Raspberry PI and I checked other (tap event related) examples and they just work fine. Once, I was unsuccessful in standalone video app for kivy, I tried a dirty trick of embedding the video on to grid layout and then binding the on_press event of the layout with a [call](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.on_stop) that exits the application. so that I could capture the event, but didn't helped. [Kivy App documentation](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.app.html) mentions this as achievable, but it isn't.
Below, is the sample code that I'm working on. PS: It'll run even on machine and one won't need a Raspberry PI to execute it.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: <UTF-8> -*-
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')

from os.path import dirname, join
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.videoplayer import Video
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.logger import Logger
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.videoplayer import VideoPlayer

class VideoPlayerApp(App):
    def build(self):
        movie = Movie()
        layout = GridLayout(cols=2)
        layout.add_widget(movie.loadMovie(source='./media/SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.mp4'))
        self.bind(on_press = self.on_stop)  #Not working :(
        return layout

    def on_stop(self):
        return True

class Movie():
    video = ObjectProperty(None)

    def loadMovie(self, **kwargs):
        filename = './media/SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.mp4'
        return VideoPlayer(source=filename, state='play', options={'eos': 'loop'})

    def check(self):
        Logger.info("film position:" + str(self.video.position))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    VideoPlayerApp().run()
```

Comment: Do you want to enable the controls of the Video Player (Play Button, Stop Button, etc)? Or do you want the application to be closed when any part of the app is touched?

Comment: Yes, I want the application to be closed when any part of the app is touched and I don't want the buttons (even though the above code might be displaying them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not need the controls, use the `kivy.uix.videoplayer.Video` class. On the other hand, `on_press` is not a valid event for `App`, `GridLayout` or `Video`, use `on_touch_down` event or define your own `on_press` event.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: <UTF-8> -*-
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.logger import Logger
from kivy.uix.videoplayer import Video

class Player(Video):
    def __init__(self,  **kwargs):
        super(Player,  self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.source = './media/SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.mp4'
        self.state='play'
        self.options={'eos': 'loop'}
        self.bind(on_touch_down = self._stop)

    def check(self):
        Logger.info("film position:" + str(self.position))

    def _stop(self,  *args):
        App.get_running_app().stop()


class VideoPlayerApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Player()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    VideoPlayerApp().run()
```